# Help with command \author for more than 2 authors

Tags: titles

I need to insert two authors name in a paper. However, the names appear separated by a comma and not with the word AND between them. 
I am using the command \author for each author and also the other related commands as \emailauthor and \address are being used for each author.

How to change to appear the names with AND between them?

Comment: Which document class are you using?

Comment: \documentclass[final,times,1p,leqno,11pt]{elsarticle}

Comment: Well, the document class authors seem to want your authors to be separated by a comma and not an "and". You probably have to change the document class or hack your way around it by using only one author command that includes both names and the "and".

Comment: http://www.elsevier.com/framework_authors/misc/elsdoc.pdf shows you an alternative way to typeset multiple authors by each having their own address block. This way you don't get an "and" but you don't get two names separated with a comma either. And it's within the style guide.

Comment: @Christian The link has changed now to https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/pdf_file/0008/56843/elsdoc-1.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `elsarticle` document class uses a comma to separate multiple authors; if you are using this document class, then I would advise you not to change the pre-stablished formatting; it was designed specifically to satisfy the requirements of Elsevier. However, if you decide to change the template, then you will need a redefinition of the internal `\@author` command, as shown below (warning: will use "and" between all authors):

```
\documentclass[final,times,1p,leqno,11pt]{elsarticle} 

\makeatletter
\def\@author#1{\g@addto@macro\elsauthors{\normalsize%
    \def\baselinestretch{1}%
    \upshape\authorsep#1\unskip\textsuperscript{%
      \ifx\@fnmark\@empty\else\unskip\sep\@fnmark\let\sep=,\fi
      \ifx\@corref\@empty\else\unskip\sep\@corref\let\sep=,\fi
      }%
    \def\authorsep{\space and\space}%
    \global\let\@fnmark\@empty
    \global\let\@corref\@empty
    \global\let\sep\@empty}%
    \@eadauthor={#1}
}
\makeatother

\title{The Title}
\author{The First Author}
\author{The Second Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]